# Spring Boot template not found if running from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I just created a new Spring Boot(2.1.8) Gradle project with Thymeleaf support based on Java 12 using Intellij IDEA Ultimate 2019.2.3.

If I create a boot jar file and execute the jar from the command line then the app works fine. So the code/template and directories should be fine.

However, if I run the app from the IDE template resolving doesn't work. I got the "usual" error:

```
Error resolving template [auth/login], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

My old projects are working fine. The problem is present only with the projects generated by IDEA 2019.2.3

The automatically generated gradle file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.8.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

I'm trying to figure it out if it is a result of an IDE settings or a problem with the generated gradle build script or something else.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947454/thymeleaf-cannot-detect-templates-inside-spring-boot-project/42947560 ?

Comment: Also tere is a note concerning IDEA in  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines

Comment: As a workaround I have switched back to IDEA 2019.1.4 and it solved the problem.